# Cognito authenticating entire EC2 instance... or so it it seems?

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, amazon-cognito

It appears as though when I sign into my application, it is storing the credentials locally on the EC2 server. I've quadruple checked my code and I can't figure out what the deal is. If KEVIN signs in from any device, the next user to sign in, or if someone refreshes their page they end up signed in as KEVIN. I am including all code that could potentially be involved in the issue. Outside of this problem, all of my interaction with cognito works great; no errors & no problems.  Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am using Node.js, Express, AWS, and Websockets on my EC2 Instance.

```js
// Accessed from server for route authentication before page render or redirection

const AmazonCognitoIdentity = require('amazon-cognito-identity-js');

module.exports = {
    ensureAuthenticated: function(req, res, next) {
        let data = { UserPoolId : 'us-east-1_7xUGRJPKq',
        ClientId : '6glign6b34c806osfhnik18cb3'
        };
        let userPool = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserPool(data);
        let cognitoUser = userPool.getCurrentUser();
        console.log(`ensuring authentication....`);
        console.log(cognitoUser);
        if (cognitoUser === null) {
            req.flash('error_msg', 'Please log in');
            res.redirect('/login');
        } else {
            cognitoUser.getSession((err, session) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    next();
                }
            }); 
        }
    },
};
```

```js
// Routes where I am seeing the problem

const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const AmazonCognitoIdentity = require('amazon-cognito-identity-js');
const { ensureAuthenticated } = require('../config/auth.js');

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.redirect('/dashboard');
});

router.get('/dashboard', ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
    res.render('dashboard', {
        layout: './layouts/dashboard-layout.ejs'
    });
});
```

```js
// Login authentication

router.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    const loginDetails = {
        Username: req.body.email,
        Password: req.body.password
    }
    const authenticationDetails = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.AuthenticationDetails(loginDetails);

    const userDetails = {
        Username: req.body.email,
        Pool: userPool
    }
    const cognitoUser = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUser(userDetails);

    cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
        onSuccess: data => {
            cognitoUser.getUserAttributes(function(err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    return;
                } else {
                    console.log('LOGIN RESULTS')
                    console.log(result[0].Value.toString());
                    let userId = result[0].Value.toString();
                    let userCity = result[2].Value.toString();
                    console.log(userId);
                    console.log(userCity);
                    res.redirect(`/dashboard/${userCity}/${userId}/`)
                };
            });
        },
        onFailure: err => {
            req.flash('error_msg', 'Invalid Credentials');
            console.error(err);
            res.redirect('/login');
        }
    })
});
```

Thank You!

UPDATE 10/21/19: Removed function that doesn't apply to the issue.

Also do not seem to have any JWT in local storage: 
[Click Here for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1mu4.png)

Comment: `return { userCity: userCity, userId: userId };` is outside the callback from `cognitoUser.getSession()` so it's always going to return something non-deterministic.  You can't mix callbacks and "return".

Comment: I am only using this as a function to return User Information, it's not actually being called for authentication. The value of `Ensure Authenticated` is what is being used for the callback to check for authentication.

Comment: Sorry let me clarify. So 1) `ensureAuthenticated:` is the first callback on the GET request, so it is NOT evaluating `cognitoUser` as `null` and it is able to retrieve the session from local storage. 2) So for whatever reason, whoever last signed in, is being returned by the `ensureAuthenticated:` middleware function, for any user anywhere that hits `'/'`or `'/dashboard'` instead of being redirected to the login page.